# ¿Cómo realizar inner join en spring boot mvc, jpa, hibernet,maven?

Tags: spring-mvc, maven, spring-boot, intellij-idea, spring-roo

Me encuentro con un problema, el punto es que no se como realizar una consulta con `inner join`.Mi *controller* es el siguiente:

- Controller:

  ```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/juan", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String updateProduct(
            @RequestParam("id") int id,
            @RequestParam("descripcion") String descripcion,
            @RequestParam("price") double price) {

        List nombre = userRepository.userdata(1);
        System.out.println("aqui data " + nombre);
        return "redirect:/inicio";
    }
  ```
- Model 1:

  ```
  @Entity
  @Table(name = "\"MFTP_USUARIO\"", schema = "public")
  public class Users implements Serializable {
      @Id
      @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
      @Column(name = "id_usuario")
      private int idusuario;

      @Column(name = "a_nombre")
      private String anombre;

      @Column(name = "a_paterno")
      private String apaterno;

      @Column(name = "a_materno")
      private String amaterno;

      @Column(name = "a_rfc")
      private String arfc;

      @Column(name = "a_usuario")
      private String ausuario;

      @Column(name = "a_contrasena")
      private String acontrasena;

      @Column(name = "c_status_id")
      private int cstatusid;

      @Column(name = "c_info_contacto_id")
      private int cinfocontactoid;

      @Column(name = "d_registro")
      private Date dregistro;

      @Column(name = "c_usuario_id")
      private int cusuarioid;

      @Column(name = "d_modifica")
      private Date dmodifica;

      @Column(name = "c_usuario_id_mod")
      private int cusuarioidmod;

      @Column(name = "c_usuario_mifel")
      private int cusuariotmifel;

      public Users(){}

      public int getIdusuario() {
          return idusuario;
      }

      public void setIdusuario(int idusuario) {
          this.idusuario = idusuario;
      }

      public String getAnombre() {
          return anombre;
      }

      public void setAnombre(String anombre) {
          this.anombre = anombre;
      }

      public String getApaterno() {
          return apaterno;
      }

      public void setApaterno(String apaterno) {
          this.apaterno = apaterno;
      }

      public String getAmaterno() {
          return amaterno;
      }

      public void setAmaterno(String amaterno) {
          this.amaterno = amaterno;
      }

      public String getArfc() {
          return arfc;
      }

      public void setArfc(String arfc) {
          this.arfc = arfc;
      }

      public String getAusuario() {
          return ausuario;
      }

      public void setAusuario(String ausuario) {
          this.ausuario = ausuario;
      }

      public String getAcontrasena() {
          return acontrasena;
      }

      public void setAcontrasena(String acontrasena) {
          this.acontrasena = acontrasena;
      }

      public int getCstatusid() {
          return cstatusid;
      }

      public void setCstatusid(int cstatusid) {
          this.cstatusid = cstatusid;
      }

      public int getCinfocontactoid() {
          return cinfocontactoid;
      }

      public void setCinfocontactoid(int cinfocontactoid) {
          this.cinfocontactoid = cinfocontactoid;
      }

      public Date getDregistro() {
          return dregistro;
      }

      public void setDregistro(Date dregistro) {
          this.dregistro = dregistro;
      }

      public int getCusuarioid() {
          return cusuarioid;
      }

      public void setCusuarioid(int cusuarioid) {
          this.cusuarioid = cusuarioid;
      }

      public Date getDmodifica() {
          return dmodifica;
      }

      public void setDmodifica(Date dmodifica) {
          this.dmodifica = dmodifica;
      }

      public int getCusuarioidmod() {
          return cusuarioidmod;
      }

      public void setCusuarioidmod(int cusuarioidmod) {
          this.cusuarioidmod = cusuarioidmod;
      }

      public int getCusuariotmifel() {
          return cusuariotmifel;
      }

      public void setCusuariotmifel(int cusuariotmifel) {
          this.cusuariotmifel = cusuariotmifel;
      }
  ```
- Model 2:

  ```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "\"MFTP_USUARIO_PERFIL\"", schema = "public")
    public class UserProfile implements Serializable{
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        @Column(name = "c_usaurio_pfl")
        private int cusauriopfl;

        @Column(name = "c_usuario_id")
        private int cusuarioid;

        @Column(name = "c_perfil_id")
        private int cperfilid;

        @Column(name = "c_status_id")
        private int cstatusid;

        @Column(name = "d_registro")
        private Date dregistro;

        @Column(name = "c_usuario_id_cap")
        private int cusuarioidcap;

        @Column(name = "d_modifica")
        private Date dmodifica;

        @Column(name = "c_usuario_id_mod")
        private int cusuarioidmod;


        public int getCperfilid() {
            return cperfilid;
        }

        public void setCperfilid(int cperfilid) {
            this.cperfilid = cperfilid;
        }

        public int getCstatusid() {
            return cstatusid;
        }

        public void setCstatusid(int cstatusid) {
            this.cstatusid = cstatusid;
        }

        public Date getDregistro() {
            return dregistro;
        }

        public void setDregistro(Date dregistro) {
            this.dregistro = dregistro;
        }

        public int getCusuarioidcap() {
            return cusuarioidcap;
        }

        public void setCusuarioidcap(int cusuarioidcap) {
            this.cusuarioidcap = cusuarioidcap;
        }

        public Date getDmodifica() {
            return dmodifica;
        }

        public void setDmodifica(Date dmodifica) {
            this.dmodifica = dmodifica;
        }

        public int getCusuarioidmod() {
            return cusuarioidmod;
        }
  ```
- Repositorio:

  ```
    public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<Users, Long> {

        Users findByAusuarioAndAcontrasena(@Param("user") String user, @Param("password") String password);


        //Table
        List<Users> findAll();

        //Delete
        List<Users> deleteByIdusuario(int id);

        //search by id
        List<Users> findAllByIdusuario(int id);

        @Query("SELECT use.idusuario,\t\n" +
                "use.anombre,\n" +
                "use.apaterno,\n" +
                "use.amaterno,\t\n" +
                "use.arfc,\t\n" +
                "use.ausuario,\t\n" +
                "use.acontrasena,\t\n" +
                "use.cstatusid,\t\n" +
                "use.cinfocontactoid,\t\n" +
                "use.dregistro,\t\n" +
                "use.cusuarioid,\t\n" +
                "use.dmodifica,\t\n" +
                "use.cusuarioidmod,\t\n" +
                "use.cusuariotmifel,\n" +
                "usep.cperfilid\n" +
                "FROM Users use\n" +
                "INNER JOIN UserProfile usep\n" +
                "ON idusuario = UserProfile.cusuarioid\n" +
                "WHERE  use.idusuario = (?1)")
        List<Users> userdata(int id);
    }
  ```

Pero no logro realizar la consulta con mi inner join.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero, creo que tendrías que declarar la relación usando la anotaciones `@OneToMany`, `@ManyToMany` , `@ManyToOne` o `@ManyToMany`

Luego, la query solo tendría que ser algo así:

```
 @Query("SELECT use from Useres fetch join use.profiles where user.id = use.idusuario = (?1)")
 List<Users> userdata(int id);
```

Para que JPA, automáticamente, te cargase los datos del modelo de una sola vez.

[Este artículo](https://www.arquitecturajava.com/jpa-join-fetch-uso/) te explica un ejemplo.

Mi consejo sería que te introdujeses un poco mas en la especificación JPA.

Buena suerte.

Answer (score 0):

Antes que nada deberías relacionar tus tablas como lo dice el compañero arriba `@OneToOne`, `@OneToMany` o `@ManyToMany` ..eso como parte de buena práctica y mejoras en el ORM.

Por otro lado, veo que usas SQL nativo, en todo caso deberías usar

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM TU_TABLA WHERE COLUMNA =: PARAM", nativeQuery = true)
```

Y al momento de enviar el parámetro `PARAM` Debería ser

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM TU_TABLA WHERE COLUMNA =: PARAM", nativeQuery = true)
public List<Entidad> nombreMetodo(@Param("PARAM") String PARAM)
```

Sino específicas el `nativeQuery`, JPA lo interpretará como consultas `JPQL`.